# NSAttributedString get images and string in parts

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have an `NSAttributedString` with a mixture of `String` and `NSTextAttachment` with images in there. How would I extract an `[AnyObject]` array of the parts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me in Swift 4:

```
extension UITextView {
    func getParts() -> [AnyObject] {
        var parts = [AnyObject]()

        let attributedString = self.attributedText
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
        attributedString.enumerateAttributes(in: range, options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (object, range, stop) in
            if object.keys.contains(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment) {
                if let attachment = object[NSAttributedStringKey.attachment] as? NSTextAttachment {
                    if let image = attachment.image {
                        parts.append(image)
                    } else if let image = attachment.image(forBounds: attachment.bounds, textContainer: nil, characterIndex: range.location) {
                        parts.append(image)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                let stringValue : String = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                if (!stringValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty) {
                    parts.append(stringValue as AnyObject)
                }
            }
        }
        return parts
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out you can iterate over all the `attributedString` and read if the object has an `NSTextAttachmentAttributeName` property. If not, assume it's a string.

```swift
extension UITextView {
    func getParts() -> [AnyObject] {
            var parts = [AnyObject]()

            let attributedString = self.attributedText
            let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
            attributedString.enumerateAttributesInRange(range, options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (object, range, stop) in

                if object.keys.contains(NSAttachmentAttributeName) {
                    if let attachment = object[NSAttachmentAttributeName] as? NSTextAttachment {
                        if let image = attachment.image {
                            parts.append(image)
                        }else if let image = attachment.imageForBounds(attachment.bounds, textContainer: nil, characterIndex: range.location) {
                            parts.append(image)
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    let stringValue : String = attributedString.attributedSubstringFromRange(range).string
                    if !stringValue.isEmptyOrWhitespace() {
                        parts.append(stringValue)
                    }
                }
            }


            return parts
        }
}
```